# How to filter a mongo collection based spark dataframe with a list of ObjectId

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, mongodb-query

I am trying to read mongodb collections using mongo-spark-connector.jar
I have 2 collections
`Agents` and `Users`, now my tasks are:

1. From Agents collection I need to pick all agentIds which is of type String.
2. Fetch the documents from Users collection based on the Agent ids that we got from Agents collection, agentId in Agent needs to be matched with userId in Users collection.

UserId in Users collection is of type `ObjectId`

```
|-- userId: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- oid: string (nullable = true)
```

I am able to pull the list of agentIds from Agents Collection:

```
val agentIdsList = agentIdsDF.withColumnRenamed("agentId","oid").as[ObjectId].distinct().collect().toList
```

The issue is when I am trying to filter the Users collection with the list of agentIds I am getting error

```
val usersDF = usersCollDF.filter(col("user").isin(agentIdsList:_*))
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class com.mongodb.spark.sql.fieldTypes.ObjectId
```

Could someone please help as how to filter mongodata based on ObjectId field.

Comment: transform List[ObjectId] to List[String], Spark expression evaluator can´t deal with Mongo ObjectId types

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez I initially tried with String instead of ObjectId but I dont get correct results. Below are corresponding Mongodb queries
Eg: ```db.getCollection('users').find({"userId" : ObjectId("5da7448418db780011401725")})``` --> this works.

```db.getCollection('profiles').find({"user" : "5da7448418db780011401725"})``` --> wrong results.